# XSLT: How to filter content from complex generated HTML pages?

Tags: xslt, filter, merge

Here can be found some very good examples how to use XSLT to filter and merge simple HTML pages.

There are a mass of single saved HTML-pages (that has been generated with ASP) like the following example, that should be filtered and merged together into one HTML to generate a book from it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="../../../../external.html?link=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1"><title>
    2021_0623.aspx
</title>
</style></head>
<body>
<div align="center">
   
<div class="aspNetHidden">
</div>
    <table width="95%" id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >   
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td width="100%" bgcolor="black" style="padding: 10px;">
        <div align="center">
            
        </div>    
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="black" width="100%" height="20px" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <div class="align-left">
        </div>
        </td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-right: 10px">
            <a href="" /></a><div id="Menu1">
    <ul class="level1">
        <li>Recent Updates</li>
    </ul>
</div><a id="Menu1_SkipLink"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="white" style="padding: 20px;"> 
            
<p class="page-title">Library</p>
<p class="page-title-2">Library Text</p>
<div class="nav">
    <table class="nav">
    <tr class="nav">
    <td class="nav-title">Some unneeded navigation</td>
    <td class="nav">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<p class="copyright">Copyright © 2021</p>
<p class="about"><strong>ABOUT THE CONTENTS.</strong></p>
<p class="text-title">Title of text</p>
<p class="text-date">August 22, 2021</p>
<p>text of interest.</p>
<p>more text of interest.</p>

<p class="separator-left-33">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="footnote"><a id="_ftn1" href="#_ftnref1" name="_ftn1">[1]</a> a footnote of interest</p>
<p class="footnote"><a id="_ftn2" href="#_ftnref2" name="_ftn1">[2]</a> one more footnote of interest</p>

<div class="nav">
<table class="nav">
</table>
</div>
    </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td width="100%" height="45" align="left" valign="top" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 5px;" bgcolor="black">
            </td>
    </tr>     
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result should be to filter all contents beginning with the **title**
`<p class="page-title">Library</p>`
including the footnotes.

Is this possible with XSLT and maybe to show up the way to do this?

It would be nice to filter the unneeded navigation and maybe class="about" that is always the same.
But this can be done in several steps afterwards.

The expected output should be like this or can be a well formed HTML-page:

```
<p class="page-title">Library</p>
<p class="page-title-2">Library Text</p>
<p class="copyright">Copyright © 2021</p>
<p class="text-title">Title of text</p>
<p class="text-date">August 22, 2021</p>
<p>text of interest.</p>
<p>more text of interest.</p>
<p class="separator-left-33">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="footnote"><a id="_ftn1" href="#_ftnref1" name="_ftn1">[1]</a> a footnote of interest</p>
<p class="footnote"><a id="_ftn2" href="#_ftnref2" name="_ftn1">[2]</a> one more footnote of interest</p>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT? And filter/merge is not really a precise description.

Comment: Yes you can. It is a good practice  at SO to post the output you want corresponding to the input above and also to post the code you have written up to now.

Comment: I just want to follow some examples using xsltproc in Linux. I have no idea which version of XSLT is needed?

Comment: At this moment i think that a solution in XSLT is to much effort, because i only understand the principles of XSLT.
So i am witing some lines in perl that are wating for the corresponding line and then output every line beginning with a "<p"

Comment: Is `<html xmlns="../../../../external.html?link=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >` really the namespace declaration in the input documents?

Comment: Yes - this is part of the input pages and much more references inside links, because the pages have been downloaded with httrack.

Comment: Yes - but it is the same with the input files. At least the processing does work with your XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xsltproc seems to have an option to process `--html` documents instead of XML ones so assuming that option allows you to parse your inputs into HTML without a namespace the XSLT 1 code

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="start-element" select="//p[@class = 'page-title']"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$start-element | $start-element/following-sibling::p"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the HTML documents end up in that odd namespace your input carries you would have to bind a prefix to that namespace in XSLT 1 and select and match element nodes with qualified names using `prefix:local-name` e.g. `xhtml:body` or `xhtml:p` where the namespace declaration would be `xmlns:xhtml="../../../../external.html?link=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

Comment: That's fine - Thank you!
"xsltproc --html -o output.html xslt.xml 1.html" is working - there are a couple of validity errors, but the output.html is what is expected.
Is it possible to filter out the class="about" ?

Comment: @Karsten, yes, add an empty template `<xsl:template match="p[@class = 'about']"/>` to block the processing of those elements.

Comment: Yes this works - thanks - the principle is clear now. The last thing that is missing is to combine mulitple filtered HTML pages again to one big HTML file that can be converted as Ebook. In Perl i implemented this already, but with XSLT there will be maybe a better solution for the footprints.

Comment: @Karsten, in XSLT 1 there is a way to process multiple or secondary input, this is done using the `document` function. I don't think it makes sense to explain it in a comment, read an introduction to XSLT and the use of the `document` function in a book like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm or any other introduction to XSLT, then try to use that, if you don't succeed, ask a separate question on that.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the basic solution as perl script doing the needed extract:

```pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $LCount = 0; # Line count
my $ICount = 0; # Line ignore count
my $DCount = 0; # Line done count
my $Line;           # actual line

if (@ARGV == 0) {       # Kein Paramter -> Beschreibung
    print "\n";
    print "extract.pl [input-file] [output-file]\n";
    print "\n";
    exit;
}

if (@ARGV < 1) { die "To less parameter!\n"; }
if (@ARGV > 2) { die "To much parameter!\n"; }

my $InputFile = $ARGV[0];
my $OutputFile = $ARGV[1];


###############################################################################
# Main programm
###############################################################################

open(InFile, $InputFile) or die "Error opening '$InputFile': $!\n";
open(OutFile,"> $OutputFile") or die "Error opening '$OutputFile': $!\n";

while(defined($Line = <InFile>)) {
    $LCount ++;

    if ($Line =~ /^<p/) {
        if ($Line =~ /class=\"about\"/) {
            $ICount ++;
        } else {
            $DCount ++;
            print OutFile $Line;
        }
    } else {
        $ICount ++;
    }
}

close(InFile) or die "Error closing '$InputFile': $! \n";
close(OutFile) or die "Error closing '$OutputFile': $! \n";

print "\n$LCount lines from $InputFile processed.\n";
print "$DCount lines extracted.\n";
print "$ICount lines ignored.\n\n";
```

With some lines more much more can be filtered out and the HTML framework is added optional.

But it is still interesting if this can be done similar simple with XSLT ...

Answer (score 0):

In this special case the basic filtering could be done in a shell with a simple grep:

```
grep "<p" 1.html > out.html
```

The perl solution is preferred, because more options in the behaviour and filtering can be implemented.